# Do we have a canonical Q&A for Android issues that are caused by outdated dependencies?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I've been seeing a lot of questions in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) about a range of issues, but all with (or likely with) the shared root cause of outdated dependencies.

Here's a recent one: [Error: 'Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version....'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53251005/error-please-fix-the-version-conflict-either-by-updating-the-version)

Here's another: [i want to add firebase with my app and i got teh following errors on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344679/i-want-to-add-firebase-with-my-app-and-i-got-teh-following-errors-on-build)

And another: [Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/Function;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230833/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-and)

And another: [Why does bthıs error happen when ı try to add fırebase to my androıd projcet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53352265/why-does-bth%C4%B1s-error-happen-when-%C4%B1-try-to-add-f%C4%B1rebase-to-my-andro%C4%B1d-projcet)

In the example I gave, OP has quite a few outdated dependencies (the probable cause of the error here is the implementation of `firebase-core` 11.8.0, while other Firebase dependencies are at 16.0.4+, although it could also be in part due to the `google-services` classpath being a whole major version behind the latest). Their issue would almost definitely be solved by simply updating their dependencies, which is easy enough:

> Click a yellow-highlighted dependency, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and select the suggested version upgrade.

However, it seems like a lot of people just don't realize the yellow highlights mean outdated or badly implemented dependencies. I've either been commenting on or answering these questions with personalized suggestions, but I know it would be better to have a canonical duplicate target. I was considering making my own, but I don't want to do that if we already have a Q&A that definitively states how to update your Gradle dependencies.

Do we have one we could link to?

Comment: There is already one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500934/error-fix-the-version-conflict-google-services-plugin but the answers there have nothing to do with what OP in that question asked. But you can add an answer there..

Comment: I mean a general "your problem is because your dependencies are outdated. Here's how to update them" type thing. Thanks though.

Comment: That could apply to a very wide array of problems. That's the programming equivalent of "did you upgrade your drivers", it's something that most people should do if the software isn't behaving as it's documented to behave to then proceed to report a bug.

Comment: @Braiam from the amount of questions I've seen where the dependencies are moderately to severely outdated, it definitely isn't what most people _do_ do. Whether or not it should be is something else entirely. And if they all have the same answer, it'd be a lot easier to just dupe them out. As I see it, it's similar to the "What is an NPE and how do I fix one?" question.

Comment: Note that I used "should". We can't fix stupidity, but we shouldn't enable it either.

Comment: @Braiam enabling it IMO would be to answer each question and give the OP undo attention and effort. We shouldn't just ignore the question, either, since it's answerable. There needs to be a middle ground.

Comment: "would be to [...] give the OP undo attention and effort" that's exactly what we shouldn't do. You should just close these questions as unclear with a single comment "have you tried upgrading your dependencies?" and be done.

Comment: But they aren't unclear at all. They aren't too broad, they aren't off-topic, etc. They're low-research questions, and not good, but they can only be closed as duplicates.

Comment: No, they can be closed as "non reproducible". Duplicates are for useful questions. These are the antonym of such questions.

Comment: @Braiam they're also reproducible. Set your dependencies to those versions and you'll get the error. As for usefulness, well, a whole lot of people have that similar issue. They're not great questions, but they're not useless.

Comment: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.** This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting." I was calling the name of the off topic reason, not just that part.