# Is this a good question for a canonical Q&A about Android Gradle dependencies?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago, I asked this question: [Do we have a canonical Q&A for Android issues that are caused by outdated dependencies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376520/do-we-have-a-canonical-qa-for-android-issues-that-are-caused-by-outdated-depend)

(I've since added a couple more examples)

It's been 5 days now, and no one seems to know of a good dupe target, although people seem to agree that we could use one. Because of that, I've decided I should try deliberately making a canonical Q&A about it.

However, I'm not that great at asking questions, especially when I already know the answer. I did this sort of thing twice before on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), but I know the SO community is pretty different, to say the least. So, before I go plunging in, I want to ask how my current draft of the question stands, and if any improvements could be made.

Here's what I have so far:

> I'm working on an Android project, but when I try to build it, I run into one of these errors, or similar:
>
> > - The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> > - Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
> > - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/Function;
> > - duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class
> > - ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class
> > - java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbq.class
> > - com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbtt.class
> > - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbo;
> > - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
> > - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
>
> The error prevents me from building. What can I do to make my project work again?
>
> (NOTE: This question seems broad, but each of the listed errors usually has a single, simple answer)

The main problem I have with it personally, is that, at first glance, it seems too broad. After all, it's "asking" about a whole ton of different-looking errors. However, they all have the same solution, so I think they fit in the same question, especially if it's meant to be a canonical dupe target.

Is this a good question for the type of Q&A pair this is?